# Issue using impdp in oracle db

Tags: database, oracle, docker, import, export

I have an licensed Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Version 19.7.0.0.0. Furthermore I have another Oracle DB in a docker container that has been created as described in [DockerFiles](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles), whihc is 18.4.0 xe.

I want to transfer the schema/data from 19c to 18.4xe. I have used the following command to export the data from 19c:

```
expdp system/pwd@db DIRECTORY=export_dir_local SCHEMAS=MYSCHEMA CONSISTENT=yes EXCLUDE=statistics COMPRESSION=all VERSION=18.1.0 DUMPFILE=mydump.dmp LOGFILE=mydump.log
```

and then in the docker I import it by using

```
impdp system/pwd@localhost/xepdb1  directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=mydump.dmp exclude=STATISTICS LOGFILE=mydump.log
```

However when I run the command I receive the following error:

```
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Mar 3 19:15:39 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
```

while the log contains:

```
;;;
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Mar 3 19:15:39 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;;
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Wed Mar 3 19:15:46 2021 elapsed 0 00:00:04
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Wed Mar 3 19:15:46 2021 elapsed 0 00:00:04
```

I have tried also to export it with COMPRESSION=NONO with the same error and by changing the version  VERSION=18 or VERSION=18.4.0

but I receive the error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39358: Export dump file version 18.4.0 not compatible with target version 18.1.0.0.0
```

Furthermore in "show parameter compatible" I receive

```
NAME              TYPE    VALUE  
----------------- ------- ------ 
compatible        string  18.0.0 
noncdb_compatible boolean FALSE
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What's the COMPATIBLE parameter in the 18.4 database? `show parameter compatible`

Comment: Also, check out [this article](https://oracle-base.com/blog/2020/02/19/data-pump-between-database-versions-its-not-just-about-the-version-parameter/) for a specific 19c to 18c issue that give this error when the timezones are incompatible.

Comment: @kfinity I added it to the article